# how to efficiently display the correct pop up window in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, popupwindow

Backstory: I'm making a very simple Rock paper scissors app. In the app you have 3 buttons to select either rock, paper, or scissors.

When you select the rock, I have a popupwindow that says "Computer plays paper you lose"

The problem is this popup message needs to be dynamic.

My goal is to have the computer randomly select a move and determine the outcome of the game which is display in a popupwindow. So for example if I choose rock and the computer chooses scissors the popup would generate the message "Computer selects scissors you win!" This is probably pretty basic to all of you but I'm still getting familiar with android development and android studio.

Is it possible to have just one popupwindow.xml file and pass values to display the correct message? Like "Computer plays 'computermov' you 'result'!"

How can I implement this? Below is page2.java which has only one of the buttons programmed to call the popupwindow. I need to make it work for all three buttons. I also included popupwindow.xml and Pop.java, a class I made that calls the popupwindow.

popupwindow.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Computer played Paper you lose!"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

page2.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitypage2);

ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonRock);
    //btn is set to the rock image needs to be dynamic
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(page2.this, Pop.class));
    }
});
}
```

Pop.java

```
public class Pop extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.popupwindow);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.4));
}
```

So what I'm thinking is that in popupwindow.xml I could hardcode all possible outcomes of the computer selection and result of the game and just display the correct popup by id at runtime. Seems like the wrong way to do it but I think that could work?

Whats a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you say 'popupwindow' are you talking about an alert? sounds like you're talking about a new activity

Comment: 'popupwindow' is just an alert.

Comment: No it's not. We don't have 'popup windows' on android or iOS. You can have alerts but not popups

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to use an `AlertDialog`, e.g.

```
String  computerSelected = ...;
boolean computerWon = ...;
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setMessage("Computer selected " + computerSelected + ". You " + (computerWon ? "loose" : " win"))
    .show();
```

Comment: would it be possible to use a ternary operator at the end like so

`(computerWon) ? "lost" : "won".show();`